# How to reference a "Android Project Library" in my "Android Project"

Tags: android, eclipse, shared-libraries

I have

- an "Android Project Library" with some classes in my Eclipse
- an Android Project in the same Eclipse.

I would like to use the classes from "Android Project Library" in my "Android Project". I managed to create the "Android Project Liibrary" (simple checkbox in the creation dialog".

But now, how do I reference this library to my "Android Project". What are the steps for ?

**UPDATE**

First try:
I just added the "Android Project Library" to my "Project properties"->"Java Build Path"->"Projects". Now I can use my classes from the "Android Project Library" in my "Android Project" without syntax Errors, but when running the app, it throws the error "NoClassDefFoundError".

Answer (score 0):

First to add a project as library

- mark that project as library

Then on project to add library

- properties -> android -> add

make sure that your dependencies are checked and at top

- properties -> java build path -> order and export

move the **android dependencies** to top and it should be checked